# Laravel 5.8 parsing HTML text from database to modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal, html-parsing, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to show HTML text which is an event program stored in database from TinyMCE textarea in a bootstrap modal. 
I need to parse it before, for that I found that Laravel 5.* uses:`{!! !!}` to parse but with $event->program it always shows the last one stored.
here is my js code

```
$('#eventDetails').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var id = button.data('id')
  var name = button.data('name')
  var description = button.data('description')
  var program = button.data('program')
  var date = button.data('date')
  var modal = $(this)

  modal.find('.modal-body #id').text(id);
  modal.find('.modal-body #name').text(name);
  modal.find('.modal-body #description').text(description);
  modal.find('.modal-body #program').text(program);
  modal.find('.modal-body #date').text(date);
});
```

so what shoud I do please !!?

Comment: where do you use `$event->program`? please include controller code

Comment: @DerekPollard I use it in the modal 
here is my show method :

'public function show($id)
    {
        $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
        return view('evente.show', compact('event'));
    }'